# MEDIANIF formula using months

Tags: excel

I've written the following "MEDIANIF" array formula to give me the median of values (percentage returns) from column B that correspond to months in column A. In other words, I want the median of all values that correspond to January, February, March, etc...

This formula works perfectly for all months, except for January. I've manually verified it is working fine for all other months, but for whatever reason, it just returns 0 for January. This isn't a formatting issue or anything like that (everything is formatted consistently). I cannot for the life of me figure out why it won't work for January.

```
=MEDIAN(IF(MONTH(Data!$A$4:$A$65536)=1,Data!$B$4:$B$65536))
```

I'd post an image, but this is my first post and I can't post pics until i have at least 10 reputation!

The data is arranged with calendar months in column A (last trading day of the month) and percentage returns (formatted as a percent) in column B.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel will treat blank cells as zero (in this sort of formula, at least) and zero will be deemed to be a date in January (January 1900) so any blank rows will contribute a zero to the January median calculation; that's why you get incorrect results - add another check to ensure that the cells aren't blank, i.e.

`=MEDIAN(IF(Data!$A$4:$A$65536<>"",IF(MONTH(Data!$A$4:$A$65536)=1,Data!$B$4:$B$65536)))`

Alternatively you could limit the formula to rows with data - perhaps employing dynamic named ranges if the amount of data is variable